# Partition a list of strings into n number of partitions which are deterministically reproducible, given n can change

Tags: python, md5, hashlib

I have this requirement wherein I need to assign every string in a list, a partition in the range [1,n] randomly. These partitions should be reproducible and should not change on varying n.

I am able to achieve the first requirement pretty easily using `hashlib` in python. The issue is the second requirement.

For eg:

```
import hashlib
string = "johndoe"
digest = hashlib.md5(string.encode()).hexdigest()
print("Partition id:", int(digest,16)%8)
```

This gives me **7** for `n = 8`. But if `n = 9`, the partition id changes to **4**

How can I retain and reproduce the partitions for a given string on varying n?

The number of partitions n is a number in [8,50]
The size of the list is < 200,000

If reproducing is not possible, is a solution with minimum movement of strings between the partitions on the cards?

Comment: Is the requirement even possible? Let's assume `n=1`, then all strings are assigned to the first partition. If you change `n`, because of the "*reproducible partition*" constraint, all strings are still necessarily assigned only to partition 1. Can you clarify a generalization?

Comment: You should also explain what is the general goal. This might help suggested an appropriate solution, if any.

Comment: @mozway that’s why n>=8 is given. To create a well partitioned dataset

Comment: this is the same with any number of groups. If `n=8` and you extend to `n=9` there can never be a hash in the 9th partition **and** respecting the "*reproducible partition*" rule...